# Как одновременно завершить несколько потоков QThread в течение определённого времени?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5

Есть код на Python 3.4 с использованием PyQt 5. В нём создаются несколько потоков из одного класса, унаследованного от `QThread`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sys import argv as sys_argv, exit as sys_exit
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread


class Thread_Worker (QThread):

    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        self.isRun = True

    def run (self):
        while self.isRun:
            time.sleep(60) # Do something

class Threads_Control (QWidget):

    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        self.threads = []

        self.resize(250, 150)
        self.move(200, 200)
        self.show()

        for i in range(50):          # Создать 50 потоков
            th = Thread_Worker()
            self.threads.append(th)  # Закинуть инстанс потока в массив
            th.start()

    def stop_all_threads (self):
        for th in self.threads:        
            th.isRun = False         # Установить флаг, что поток должен остановиться
            if (not th.wait(5000)):  # Ждать завершения потока 5 секунд
                th.terminate()       # Если не завершился за это время, завершить насильно 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys_argv)

    tc = Threads_Control()
    tc.stop_all_threads()

    sys_exit(app.exec_())
```

Как хотелось бы чтобы работало: Создаются 50 потоков, каждый из которых имеет флаг `isRun`, отвечающий за то, должен ли поток продолжать работу или нет.

Затем, когда нужно их все завершить, меняем флаг у каждого из них на `False`, и тут же даём каждому из них 5 секунд на корректное завершение работы. Если за 5 секунд не завершились, завершаем насильно с помощью метода `terminate()`.

Проблема в том, что метод `wait(5000)` у воркера блокирует основной поток на указанное время (5 сек, в моём случае) при каждой итерации цикла.

В худшем случае, чтобы завершить 50 запущенных потоков, которые не смогли завершиться сами за 5 секунд, понадобится 50 * 5 = 250 сек, то есть больше 4 минут, что абсолютно не приемлемо.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как всем 50 потокам сообщить **одновременно**, что они должны завершиться в течение 5 секунд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плохо знаком с Питоном, точнее вообще не знаком, но по идее Вам тут требуется асинхронное выполнение.

Необходимо отправлять сигнал из каждого потока в тот момент времени, когда последний уже вышел из своего цикла выполнения и готов завершить работу. Если в питоне класс `QThread` не отправляет обозначенный сигнал, то создайте свой собственный.

Подключите этот сигнал в какой-нибудь слот (я к сожалению не в курсе, правильно ли называть функцию слотом в контексте Питона), где из масива `self.threads` будете удалять объект только что завершившего свою работу потока. В этом же слоте, проверяете, остались ли в `self.threads` ещё потоки. Если остались, то ничего не делаем. Если пусто, то как бы и всё на этом, все потоки завершили свою работу, выходим из программы или ещё чего-нибудь этакое по ситуации.

Разумеется, что потоки необходимо иметь возможность информировать, когда им следует перейти к процессу завершения работы. Тут у Вас правильно: просто перебор всех потоков в цикле с установкой соответствующего флага, но только без ожидания:

```
for th in self.threads:        
   th.isRun = False
```

Далее, как только все будут уведомлены о необходимости прикрыть лавочку, запускаем таймер на нужное нам максимальное время ожидания. Если все потоки завершатся быстрее, чем сработает таймер, то `self.threads` будет пуст. Если же кто-то из них не успеет, то по ним уже в цикле можно пройтись командой на уничтожение.